# Won't go into gear (rare occasion)

Tags: nissan, clutch, manual-transmission, shifting, x-trail

I have a Nissan X-Trail T30. Recently, I noticed that the car won't go into gear from time to time. Most of the time, it drives just fine. It happens after driving quite a distance. I didn't notice any difference on how the clutch feels. At first I thought I forgot to use the clutch. When it happens, the stick feels just like when I'm trying to shift without depressing the clutch pedal. I feel the "wall", and the transmission complains(that horrible grinding noise). It usually happens when the car is at a complete stop. Especially, trying to reverse. It did happen once when I revved up so high at 1st gear and shifted to 2nd. Luckily, it doesn't happen when I'm driving. So, I just wait for a bit till the clutch functions again.

Other than that, I hear low squeak when I use the clutch. I think it comes from the slave cylinder, which needs some lubrication. The clutch functions just fine. I don't think it has anything to do with the problem I'm describing here.

It seems that I'm the only one experiencing this symptom. No one talks about having this problem on the internet. I think it could be the moist in the clutch line. The clutch and the brake system shares the same reservoir. The fluid level is near max. But I doubt the mechanics flushed the clutch line when they changed the brake fluid last time.

Am I diagnosing the problem right? Would bleeding the clutch line(and also lubricating the slave cylinder) solve the problem?

Comment: This can sometimes happen depending on how you shift and how old the transmission is. If the transmission synchronizers are worn out or sometimes just if the gears are a little too much out of phase with each other, a shift from 2nd to first can be hard. When this happens, put the transmission into neutral, release the clutch, re-engage the clutch and attempt the shift again, normally it will work after fully engaging the transmission in neutral with the clutch released as this gets the input side of the transmission spinning.

Comment: I solved the problem by adjusting the clutch pedal. I noticed that the clutch had been dragging the entire time. I think it dragged because the components along the clutch line expanded as the car heated up.

Comment: I know this indicates that the master cylinder is going out. But the car will be wrecked by the time it reaches the limit.

Answer (score -1):

Re reversing in xtrail. Read that if u brake as well as clutch when changing into reverse OR go into 4th only using the clutch before changing into reverse its easier to go into reverse. I tried both of these and they worked.